# Chosen / Select2 Style Library for Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, javascript

I've been using the [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) library in my web application to replace the default select elements, and I really like how the library looks and how easy it is to use. Now, I'm trying to implement an autocomplete feature for a text field on the same application and I want to use a library that looks similar to Select2. (To keep the UI consistent.) Are there any such libraries that you know of? (Google isn't helping.)

Answer (score 0):

select2 is also an autocomplete library and can replace both select elements and input elements.